# Regular Expression Map Implementation in Java

Tags: java, regex, dictionary, data-structures

Is there any Java implementation of Map which keys are Regex pattern. Is it possible for such kind of data structure?
Found several handmade solutions like https://wiki.apache.org/jakarta/RegexpKeyedMap, but I want a well tested library.

As a client I want this

```
map.put('^RESOURCE.*', () -> { /* some action*/});
map.put('USER|ACCOUNT', () -> { /* do action*/}};
map.put('PRODUCT', () -> { /* do action */}};
```

And e.g.

```
String entityType = 'RESOURCE_TYPE_1';
.....
Supplier<MyBatisMapper> action = mapers.get(entityType)
MyBatisMapper mapper = action.get();
mapper.update(entity);
```

It is going to be used as a static configuration. So remove functionality is not essential.

**EDITED**

Currently we have several large switches in our project and the task is make condition more complex. Like (in pseudo code):

```
switch (type) {
    case 'USER' || 'ACCOUNT' : doAction();
    case startsWith('RESOURCE'): doAnotherAction();
    ...
   /* another 10-15 cases */
}
```

I doubt what is the optimal approach. Have several ideas, but none looks nice:

- change switch with if/else
- make some RegEx container like  [dimo414](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113632/dimo414) proposed.
- create some classes for configuration. This looks too complex for the problem.

I solved this pretty easy in groovy, making

```
def configuration = [
  [matcher: { it.startsWith('RESOURCE' }, action: { /* */}],
  [matcher: { it == 'USER' || it == 'ACCOUNT' }, action: { /* */}]
]
...
def result = configuration.find({ it.matcher(type)}).action();
```

But for Java such solution will be too dirty (due to type casting).

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: I would definitely avoid that `RegexpKeyedMap` type - it's pre-Java-6 syntax and isn't correctly implemented (e.g. it doesn't implement `containsKey()` or `putAll()`).

Comment: "*But for Java such solution will be too dirty (due to type casting)*" I don't understand what you mean, where is casting an issue? Using `RegexLookup` you'd say `configuration.putPattern("^RESOURCE.*", () -> ...);` and so on then get the operation back again with `configuration.find(someString);`. Are you having trouble with the `V` type? Use `Function` or one of the other types in [`java.util.function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) has a fairly complex contract that will be difficult (or impossible) to properly follow with the data structure you're describing. For example, there's no meaningful way to implement `.entrySet()`, since there are unlimited valid keys. Furthermore, the behavior of this "map" doesn't really match the conceptual purpose of a `Map`, as lookups are expensive (likely *O(nk)*, where *k* is the complexity of the pattern).

I'd suggest avoiding implementing `Map` and instead defining a dedicated class that just supports the behavior you need. This might look something like:

```
/**
 * Associates a series of regular expressions with values, allowing the values
 * to be looked up by strings that match a pattern.
 *
 * Note this is a linear-time operation, and that patterns are checked in
 * insertion order.
 */
public class RegexLookup<V> {
  // Pattern doesn't override .equals()/.hashCode(), so it can't be the map key
  // use a LinkedHashMap to ensure ordered search
  private final LinkedHashMap<String, Pattern> patterns = new HashMap<>();
  private final HashMap<String, V> values = new HashMap<>();

  /** Associates a regular expression with a value */
  public void putPattern(String regex, V value) {
    putPattern(Pattern.compile(regex), regex);
  }

  /** Associates a regular expression with a value */
  public void putPattern(Pattern pattern, V value) {
    patterns.put(pattern.pattern(), pattern);
    values.put(pattern.pattern(), value);
  }

  /**
   * Looks for a pattern matching the given string, and returns the associated
   * value. If not match is found, returns {@link Optional#absent}.
   */
  public Optional<V> find(String string) {
    for (Entry<String, Pattern> e : patterns.entrySet()) {
      if (e.getValue().matcher(string).matches()) {
        return Optional.of(values.get(e.getKey()));
      }
    }
    return Optional.absent();
  }

  /** Returns a read-only view of the underlying pattern:value mapping. */
  public Map<String, V> asPatternMap() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(values);
  }
}
```

There's a number of benefits to composition rather than inheritence. In addition to not needing to implement the full `Map` contract, we can also give our methods clearer names and better signatures. `.find()` clearly conveys we're doing a possibly-expensive search, unlike `.get()` which is generally implied to be fast.

Your example would end up looking like this (you'll likely want a standard [functional interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) as the `V` type, but it depends on what you need):

```
RegexLookup<...> configuration = new RegexLookup();
configuration.putPattern('^RESOURCE.*', () -> { /* some action*/});
configuration.putPattern('USER|ACCOUNT', () -> { /* do action*/}};
configuration.putPattern('PRODUCT', () -> { /* do action */}};
```

Then you can retrieve the actions with:

```
Optional<...> action = configuration.find(someString);
```

---

There's some possible improvements to this implementation that *might* allow us to do better than *O(nk)*, such as constructing conjuctions (`|`) of patterns and doing essentially a binary search, but the overhead of doing additional regex searches might not be worthwhile (the complexity becomes *O(log(n) * k^2)*, I think), so I'd definitely want to benchmark anything more intricate than the above implementation.

Comment: Finally used this approach will lambda expressions for V

Comment: Glad to hear it helped.